# Error with ICEfaces 3 Tool bundle for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, icefaces

currently I try to integrate [ICEfaces 3 Tool bundle](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Using+ICEfaces+Eclipse+plugin+(for+3.3.0_P01+and+earlier+versions).) for eclipse(`Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)`), but I've got this error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: ICEfaces Tooling for Eclipse
>   (Core) 3.3.4.201309251434
>   (org.icefaces.eclipse.jst.feature.feature.group 3.3.4.201309251434)
>   Missing requirement: ICEfaces Tooling for Eclipse (Core)
>   3.3.4.201309251434 (org.icefaces.eclipse.jst.core 3.3.4.201309251434) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common [1.2.2,1.5.0)' but it
>   could.

How I can fix this bug ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: same problem :(